# Rethrow AssertionErrors in Reactor StepVerifier using Schedulers.single()

Tags: java, project-reactor

We are using [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/)  to run a particular operation asynchronously as per the code in `ServiceTest` below. To test this code, as per `ServiceTest` below, when setting up the [Mono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) for the async operation we make the Mono pass it's result to a DirectProcessor with `doOnNext` that the test has access to, and then carry out our test call and assertions with [StepVerifier](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html).

The JavaDoc of [StepVerifier#assertNext](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.Step.html#assertNext-java.util.function.Consumer-) reads

> Any [AssertionErrors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) thrown by the consumer will be rethrown during verification.

We have found that is true *only* when the immediate scheduler ([Schedulers.immediate()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#immediate--)) is used and is not true when the single scheduler ([Schedulers.single()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#single--)) is used. When the single scheduler is used, AssertionErrors are not re-thrown, i.e. the test always passes.

Is it possible, and if so, how, to use the single scheduler and have AssertionErrors rethrown during verification as per the JavaDoc?

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Service implements WithReactive, WithTestProcessor<Response> {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private DirectProcessor<Response> processor = DirectProcessor.create();

    @Setter
    private Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.single();

    public void doAction() {
        Mono.fromSupplier(this::doActionAsync)
            .doOnNext(processor::onNext)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe();
    }

    private Response doActionAsync() {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

```java
public interface WithReactive {
    void setScheduler(Scheduler scheduler);
}
```

```java
public interface WithTestProcessor<T> {
    void setProcessor(DirectProcessor<T> processor);
    DirectProcessor<T> getProcessor();
}
```

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private Collection<WithTestProcessor> withTestProcessors;

    @Before
    public void setTestProcessors() {
        withTestProcessors.forEach(withTestProcessor -> withTestProcessor.setProcessor(DirectProcessor.create()));
    }

    @Inject
    private Collection<WithReactive> withReactives;

    @Before
    public void makeReactiveSynchronous() {
        withReactives.forEach(withReactive -> withReactive.setScheduler(Schedulers.immediate()));
    }

    @Test
    private void test() {
      StepVerifier.create(service.getProcessor())
          .then(service::doAction)
          .assertNext(response -> assertThat(logExtractor.getInsertsByTable("assets")).hasSize(1))
          .thenCancel()
          .verify();
    }
}
```

Comment: update: the issue will be resolved in upcoming reactor-core v3.1.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of three factors: the initial `then`, the fact that subscription happens in parallel of the verification due to `subscribeOn` and the `thenCancel`.

One workaround is to give enough time to the `onNext` to happen before the StepVerifier executes `thenCancel`, by putting a `thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(10))` before the `thenCancel`.

Comment: I'm not sure yet if there's an easy way to protect the `StepVerifier` against this case :( opened https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/959